# Query builder Eloquent using Eager Loading in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Having a typical squeme with post & comments where a post have many comments and a comment belongs to one post:

**Post Model:**

```
 public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

**post migration:**

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');         
    });
```

**Comment model:**

```
 public function Post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App/Post', 'id');
}
```

**Comment migration:**

```
   Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('date_comment');
        $table->unsignedInteger('post_id')->nullable()->default(null);
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
        });
```

I would like use eager loading in Laravel.

For example. How Can I obtain ***all posts with his most recent comment*** using eager loading?

I tried this:

```
$post = Post::with('comments:post_id, date_comment')->get();
```

But like this I obtain all comments. Any help please?

Best regards

EDIT:

foreach statement (Blade):

```
   @foreach($posts as $post)            
            <td>{{ $post->name }}</a></td>
            <td>
            {{ !empty($post->comments[0]) ? $post->comments[0]-> 
                date_comment : '' }}
            </td>                                      
   @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [constrain eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

```
$posts = Post::with(['comments' => function($qry) {
    $qry->select('id','date_comment')->orderBy('date_comment', 'desc')->first();
}])->get();
```

Using this you can access **all posts with their most recent comment**.

If using the `select` method on query don't forget to add `id` field in the list.

To access `date_comment` of comments :

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    var_dump(!empty($post->comments[0]) ? $post->comments[0]->date_comment : '');
}
```

Comment: Why dd(post->comments); return a empty collection? I have alot of comments related in each post

Comment: If you are using the exact variable name from my answer then `$post` would holding a **collection of posts**. You should loop it and call the relation on individual post.

Comment: Yes. I mean:  `foreach($posts as $post){ $post->lastOperation }` this return all fields of comments. How Can I obtain just 'date_comment' field?

Comment: in your closure use `$qry->select('date_comment')->orderBy(...`

Comment: @JJMontalban Answer updated.You should add the `id` column in the select clause even if you don't use it. It is mandatory.

Comment: If I use  `$qry->->select('id','date_comment')->orderBy('date_comment', 'desc')->first();` return empty collection. But if I use `$qry->orderBy('date_comment', 'desc')->first();` retunr all fields. ?¿  In my foreach I use `$post->comments`.

Comment: @JJMontalban Answer updated. Please add your `foraech` statement to the question.

Comment: You are a ninja my friend

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

You need to make one more relation to retrieve the latest comment.

**Post.php**

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}

public function latestComment(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Comment')->orderBy('date_comment', 'desc');
}
```

Now You can retrieve it like this.

```
$posts = Post::with('latestComment')->get();
```

**Note: Not tested.**

Comment: But how can obtain last comment? if I use `$post->lastComment` in foreach his value is null

Comment: @JJMontalban Have you tried? If a post doesn't have a comment then it returns null.

Comment: Maybe your relationship isn't setup correctly or Post doesn't have comments. `Post::with('comments')->get()`returns anything? Check that first.

Comment: Yes I tried. And return a collection. I mean return all fields of comment. How Can I obtain just date_comment field. If I put `$post->lasComment->date_comment`  thrown an error

Comment: @JJMontalban I update code. Now you have to check $post->lastComment is not null then you can retrieve date_comment.

Comment: Result is the same. `$post->lastComment` return all fields (id, date_comment & post_id) of most recent comment

Comment: @JJMontalban You can check `$post->lastComment[0] ? $post->lastComment[0]->date_comment : ""`

Comment: This is the correct way of doing the requested. I am not sure why @JJMontalban could not make it work. Maybe the relation needs a `->limit(1)` clause.